# django views and context foreign key data

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have a model called Game that has a ManyToManyField to User

```
class Game(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False)
    image = models.URLField(blank=True)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='game', blank=True)
    port = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

And a view

```
class Dashboard(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'dashboard.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['games'] = Game.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        return super(Dashboard, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        context = super(Dashboard, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        return context
```

all this works, the issue I am having in my head is, what is the best way to access the Game data. In my template I can do either of the following to access the game data.

1.
use the User object like this

```
{% for g in user.game.all %}
```

2. 
or use the games object which was specifically passed in from the View

```
{% for g in games %}
```

Although both work, is there a recommended way to do this kind of thing or are they both valid?

if not both valid, wonder what the for and against are for each method

Cheers

Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that using the RelatedManager to access them would be best. That is your first example, `{% for g in user.game.all %}` It is built-in and designed for this purpose, to access related models easily. I'm no expert, but since you asked, I figured I would share my opinion for what it's worth...

Comment: I agree with you. There really isn't any need for the OP to be looking up Game.objects in the view since it's readily accessible from the user. UNLESS there is a need to do some more filtering on the queryset from the view.